# sum of the first $n^2$ natural numbers closed form

Tags: proof-verification, summation, alternative-proof, natural-numbers

Before I get downvoted I am still a beginner so please bare with me. I know the summation of the first n are $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.
Does that imply the sum of the first $n^2$ is $\frac{n^2(n^2+1)}{2}$?

Comment: In a word, yes.

Comment: Why do you say yes? I thought that the closed-form expression for the sum of the first $n^2$ numbers was $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$ No?

Comment: @MichaelRybkin No. That's the sum of the first $n$ squares. The OP is asking for the sum of the first $n^2$ numbers.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now.

Answer (score 3):

As you know, we have that $$\sum_{k=1}^m k = 1 + 2 + \cdots + m = \frac{m(m+1)}{2}.$$This is true for any counting number (natural number) $m$. Therefore, by using this formula with $m = n^2$ for some $n$, gives $$\sum_{k=1}^{n^2} k = 1 + 2 + \cdots + n^2 = \frac{n^2(n^2+1)}{2}.$$